# Containers on different hosts are not reachable

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

I have a stack with 2 servcies:
1. dockercloud/haproxy as load balancer
2. mycustom/nginx for ssl termination

I have 2 hosts and each service has 2 containers. One on every host.
Host 1:
* Haproxy-1 (IP: 10.7.0.9)
* Nginx-1 (IP: 10.7.0.7)

Host 2:
* Haproxy 2 (IP: 10.7.0.10)
* Nginx 2 (IP: 10.7.0.8)

The problem is that i can't connect from a container on host 1 to a container on host 2.
When connecting on host 1 and trying to traceroute Haproxy 2 (10.7.0.7) i get this:

> traceroute to 10.7.0.7 (10.7.0.7), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets 1
>   10.7.255.254 (10.7.255.254) 2997.863 ms !H 2997.704 ms !H 2997.684 ms !H

Any suggestions how to fix this?

**Edit**

docker info

```
Containers: 12
 Running: 11
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 1
Images: 12
Server Version: 1.11.1-cs1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 90
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: null host bridge weavemesh
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-4-amd64
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 5.813 GiB
Name: Debian-85-jessie-64-minimal
ID: BV3I:KVWH:L45Q:CV2D:IOTX:BG7W:YAUV:S4QG:AJ44:BTVK:J3VJ:RWJA
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No memory limit support
WARNING: No swap limit support
WARNING: No kernel memory limit support
WARNING: No oom kill disable support
WARNING: No cpu cfs quota support
WARNING: No cpu cfs period support
```

docker version

```
Client:
 Version:      1.11.1-cs1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   bfd1f99
 Built:        Wed Apr 27 22:35:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.11.1-cs1
 API version:  1.23
 Go version:   go1.5.4
 Git commit:   bfd1f99
 Built:        Wed Apr 27 22:35:34 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

docker network ls

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
719bbcb667f2        bridge              bridge
acb91ed95ada        dockercloud         weavemesh
c4be8b540ad6        host                host
c57e28b9d274        none                null
8d3859eb8bfd        weave               weavemesh
```

I used dockercloud to setup the services. So i didn't use any commands on my own.

**EDIT 2**

Here is ifconfig of nginx-1:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:07                                                                                                                  
          inet addr:172.17.0.7  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0                                                                                                          
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:7%32596/64 Scope:Link                                                                                                           
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                                                                                                             
          RX packets:530 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                                                           
          TX packets:10 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                                                          
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                                                                                                                      
          RX bytes:45267 (44.2 KiB)  TX bytes:956 (956.0 B)                                                                                                              

ethwe1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr DE:1C:3F:DF:E9:0C                                                                                                                  
          inet addr:10.7.0.7  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0                                                                                                            
          inet6 addr: fe80::dc1c:3fff:fedf:e90c%32596/64 Scope:Link                                                                                                      
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1410  Metric:1                                                                                                             
          RX packets:62 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                                                            
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                                                           
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                                                                                                                      
          RX bytes:5164 (5.0 KiB)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)
```

Here is ifconfig of nginx-2:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:AC:11:00:08                                                                                                                  
          inet addr:172.17.0.8  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0                                                                                                          
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:acff:fe11:8%32566/64 Scope:Link                                                                                                           
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1                                                                                                             
          RX packets:174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                                                           
          TX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                                                          
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                                                                                                                      
          RX bytes:14399 (14.0 KiB)  TX bytes:2076 (2.0 KiB)                                                                                                             

ethwe1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B2:A0:36:AF:0B:95                                                                                                                  
          inet addr:10.7.0.8  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0                                                                                                            
          inet6 addr: fe80::b0a0:36ff:feaf:b95%32566/64 Scope:Link                                                                                                       
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1410  Metric:1                                                                                                             
          RX packets:643722 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0                                                                                                        
          TX packets:369311 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                                                                      
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0                                                                                                                                      
          RX bytes:66498273 (63.4 MiB)  TX
```

bytes:31055890 (29.6 MiB)

Comment: Are you using legacy Swarm or the new "Swarm mode"? Give us more info and include `docker version`, `docker info`, `docker network ls`. Also add the commands you use to create your services and network.

Comment: Because i used dockercloud to deploy the setup i didn't use any commands on commandline. What other information can i provide to you?

Comment: Which network are the containers joining? `docker inspect` on your containers, I'm interested in the "Networks" section near the end.

Comment: Could you share the stack yml?